Windows 11 24H2 setting clock incorrectly automatically
I have a Surface Pro X that (I assume) is setting the hardware clock automatically via GPS, since it has a cell modem.
The problem, the hardware clock is being set to UTC, and when Windows reads this clock, it's setting it as local time.
I set the RealTimeIsUniversal registry key, but it seems to have not made any difference. If I look in Event Viewer, I can see that Windows seems to know that it should be accounting for a UTC hardware clock, however it doesn't seem to care.
The system time has changed to ‎2024‎-‎11‎-‎02T05:48:03.500000000Z from ‎2024‎-‎11‎-‎02T01:48:03.207569700Z.
Time Delta: 14400292 ms

Change Reason: System time synchronized with the hardware clock.
Process: '' (PID 4).

RTC time: ‎2024‎-‎11‎-‎02T05:48:03.500000000Z
Current time zone bias: 240
RTC time is in UTC: true
System time was based on RTC time: false

It sees that the RTC is set to 05:48, that the RTC is UTC, and still sets System time to 05:48.

Did you make a typo when you said you modified RealTimeIsUniveral? The correct spelling of that key is RealTimeIsUniversal although if you did that, you would be telling Windows, you want to use UTC based off the RTC of the system instead of converting it to your local time zone. However, based on your output, the system is NOT configured to use the RTC.

@Ramhound yes, just corrected the typo in the message. I just checked and unfortunately, there was no typo in the registry, so that isn't my issue.
